# ERROR 9952 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to fetch data from database in my spring boot application. I am using hibernate libraries. Below is my entity class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "MU_GM_CIRCULARS")
public class GmCirculars extends ParentEntity implements Serializable {

    private BigDecimal id;
    private Date createdOn;
    private String title;
    private BigDecimal serialNo;
    private BigDecimal year;
    private BigDecimal active;
    private BigDecimal organizationId;
    private BigDecimal showOnDashboard;

    public GmCirculars() {
        super();
    }

    public GmCirculars(BigDecimal id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }


    public GmCirculars(BigDecimal id, BigDecimal createdById, Date createdOn, String title, BigDecimal serialNo,
            BigDecimal year ,BigDecimal documentId, BigDecimal typeId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        this.title = title;
        this.serialNo = serialNo;
        this.year = year;

    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="MU_GM_CIRCULARS_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="MU_GM_CIRCULARS_SEQ",sequenceName="MU_GM_CIRCULARS_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="created_on")
    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @Column(name="title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Column(name="serial_no")
    public BigDecimal getSerialNo() {
        return serialNo;
    }

    public void setSerialNo(BigDecimal serialNo) {
        this.serialNo = serialNo;
    }

    @Column(name="year")
    public BigDecimal getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(BigDecimal year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Column(name = "org_id")
    public BigDecimal getOrganizationId() {
        return organizationId;
    }

    public void setOrganizationId(BigDecimal organizationId) {
        this.organizationId = organizationId;
    }

    @Column(name="show_on_dashboard")
    public BigDecimal getShowOnDashboard() {
        return showOnDashboard;
    }

    public void setShowOnDashboard(BigDecimal showOnDashboard) {
        this.showOnDashboard = showOnDashboard;
    }

    @Column(name = "active")
    public BigDecimal isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(BigDecimal active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

Here's the class with the method that fetches the data:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class GmCircularsDaoImpl extends ParentDAO implements IGmCircularsDAO {

@Override
public List<GmCirculars> find(GmCirculars obj, boolean activeOnly, int startOffset, int maxRows) {
    Session session = null;
    List<GmCirculars> discounts = null;

    try {
        if (null != obj) {

            session= this.getSession();

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(GmCirculars.class);

            if (null != obj.getId() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getId())) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", obj.getId()));
            }

            if (StringUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(obj.getTitle())) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("title", obj.getTitle(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
            }

            if(null != obj.getOrganizationId()) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("organizationId", obj.getOrganizationId()));
            }

            if (null != obj.getSerialNo() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getSerialNo())) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("serialNo", obj.getSerialNo()));
            }

            if (null != obj.getYear() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getYear())) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("year", obj.getYear()));
            }


            if (activeOnly) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active", BigDecimal.ONE));
            } else {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.ne("active", CommonConstants.DELETED_STATUS), Restrictions.isNull("active"))); //Except for deleted ones -> NVL(active,2)
            }

            criteria.setFirstResult(startOffset);
            criteria.setMaxResults(maxRows);

            criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
            criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

            System.out.println("criteria: "+ criteria.toString());
            discounts = criteria.list();
            System.out.println("returned list from db:"+discounts);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return discounts;
}
```

I try to access the database exactly on the line:

```
discounts = criteria.list();
```

which is in the method `find(GmCirculars obj, boolean activeOnly, int startOffset, int maxRows)`

When I run my code, I am getting the following errors.

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951) ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513) ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227) ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195) ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:876)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1498)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
>   ~[ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
>   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
>   ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
>   at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.sequenceInformationList(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:403)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:268)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
>   ................................................................................
>
> 2020-02-03 09:16:11.269  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
>   2020-02-03 09:16:11.281  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   2020-02-03 09:16:11.299  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
>   2020-02-03 09:16:11.367  WARN 9952 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
>   2020-02-03 09:16:11.368  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
>   2020-02-03 09:16:11.470  WARN 9952 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
>   2020-02-03 09:16:11.646  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
>   2020-02-03 09:16:12.754  WARN 9952 --- [  restartedMain] ockingLoadBalancerClientRibbonWarnLogger : You already have RibbonLoadBalancerClient on your classpath. It will be used by default. As Spring Cloud Ribbon is in maintenance mode. We recommend switching to BlockingLoadBalancerClient instead. In order to use it, set the value of `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled` to `false` or remove spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon from your project.
>   2020-02-03 09:16:12.794  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
>   2020-02-03 09:16:12.846  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
>   2020-02-03 09:16:12.900  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.231  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.231  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.385  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.385  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.586  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.751  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.751  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.751  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.751  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.751  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.751  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.751  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.932  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.935  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.937  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.940  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1580706973939 with initial instances count: 1
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.943  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application CIRCULARS-MICROSERVICE with eureka with status UP
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.944  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1580706973943, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
>   2020-02-03 09:16:13.947  INFO 9952 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
>   DiscoveryClient_CIRCULARS-MICROSERVICE/HQTPM00184606D.ADM.local:circulars-microservice:8081: registering service...
>   2020-02-03 09:16:14.002  INFO 9952 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
>   DiscoveryClient_CIRCULARS-MICROSERVICE/HQTPM00184606D.ADM.local:circulars-microservice:8081 - registration status: 204
>   2020-02-03 09:16:14.029  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
>   2020-02-03 09:16:14.031  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8081
>   2020-02-03 09:16:14.266  INFO 9952 --- [  restartedMain] ae.gov.adm.CircularsMicroservice         : Started
>   CircularsMicroservice in 10.925 seconds (JVM running for 11.768) done
>   2020-02-03 09:16:19.478  INFO 9952 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
>   2020-02-03 09:16:19.479  INFO 9952 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
>   2020-02-03 09:16:19.498  INFO 9952 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in
>   18 ms
>   Circular Microservice called.....Params are:1, false, 0
>   entity manager instantiated...
>   2020-02-03 09:16:19.829  WARN 9952 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000022: Hibernate's
>   legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA
>   javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
>   criteria: CriteriaImpl(ae.gov.adm.saeed.hibernate.entity.GmCirculars:this[][organizationId=1, active<>2 or active is null])
>   2020-02-03 09:16:19.973  WARN 9952 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 923, SQLState:
>   42000
>   2020-02-03 09:16:19.973 ERROR 9952 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not
>   found where expected
>
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
>   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
>   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1859)
>   at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:370)
>   at ae.gov.adm.saeed.dao.impl.GmCircularsDaoImpl.find(GmCircularsDaoImpl.java:111)
>   at ae.gov.adm.saeed.dao.impl.GmCircularsDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$464553b0.invoke()
>   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
>   at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
>   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
>   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
>   at ae.gov.adm.saeed.dao.impl.GmCircularsDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aedf9fbb.find()
>   at ae.gov.adm.saeed.service.CircularsService.fetchAllCircularsForOrganization(CircularsService.java:66)
>   at ae.gov.adm.CircularsMicroservice.getAllCircularsForOrganization(CircularsMicroservice.java:54)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
>   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
>   ... 83 more

Comment: Do you have table available? As in logs, we are getting "table or view does not exist".

Comment: yes I do, but i don't know which table it refers to !

Answer (score 0):

try to check if the table "MU_GM_CIRCULARS" exists in the database (probably yes) and whether you have access to it (probably not).

Connect the database using the credentials your code is using. Try the following

```
select * from dba_tables where table_name = 'MU_GM_CIRCULARS';
```

If there are any records, it means table exists in the system.

Next try this

```
select * from all_tables where table_name = 'MU_GM_CIRCULARS';
```

This will show if user has access to the table. If the table appears to be in the result, then check the "owner" column and try to reach the table using the following format

```
select * from owner.table_name
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

It is a configuration issue of the database. I was adding a config.xml file, which is NOT needed in Spring Boot. Rather, I added these values to my application.properties file, and then everything worked fine.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx
```